# PHP: How to capture var_dump recursion with __debuginfo

Tags: php, debugging, recursion, magic-methods

```
var_dump
```

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored *recursively* with values indented to show structure.

Since `var_dump` explores objects recursively and `__debuginfo` can be used to change the output of `var_dump`.

Then, is it possible to detect the top most object where the `var_dump` recursion started and return output based on certain condition?

For Example:

```php
public function __debuginfo() {

   $debug = array(
     'name' => 'Ucscode',
     'profession' => 'programming'
   );
   
  if( $this != 'The object passed by user to var_dump' ) return $debug;

  return array('type' => "The object");

}
```

**Update:**

I tried something like this and it worked

```php
public function __debuginfo() {

    global $customDebugLevel; // a counter;
    if( is_null($customDebugLevel) ) $customDebugLevel = -1; // 1st init
    $customDebugLevel++; // increase per var_dump call

    $debug = array(
        'name' => 'Ucscode',
        'profession' => 'programming',
        'child' => $this->child
    );

    if( empty($customDebugLevel) ) return $debug;

    return array('type' => "The object");

}
```

The problem however is that if `var_dump` is called twice on an instance of same class, it will not reset the `$customDebugLevel` therefore, only the first `var_dump` call will produce the correct result

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any built-in way. But you can set a variable to the top-level object before calling `var_dump()`, and compare with that.

```
public function __debuginfo() {
  global $debug_object;
  if( $this != $debug_object ) {
    return array('type' => "recursion");
  } else return array('type' => "The object");
}
...
$debug_object = $my_object;
var_dump($my_object);
```

You can encapsulate this in a function:

```
function my_var_dump($object) {
    global $debug_object;
    $debug_object = $object;
    var_dump($object);
    $debug_object = null;
}
```

Comment: It's a nice answer. I was editing my post to show what I've tried and it's quite similar to the above. Now I'm only thinking of an efficient way to unset the global variable for the next `var_dump` call

Comment: I've added a function to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of custom function. Especially outside of the class

Comment: It's just a convenience so you don't have to assign the variable explicitly every time. If you prefer the latter, go with it.